# jQuery trigger equivalent in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using AngularJS in my project and I don't want to include jQuery.
I want to perform jQuery equivalent of this in AngularJS

```
$('.someclass').trigger('create');
```

I searched in internet but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AngularJS has jqLite built into it. Refer the docs to see the available methods

[Angular jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

**For your scenario:**

`$` will not work in angularJS, `angular.element` is the equivalent of `$`.
but jqLite being very limited does not support "selectors by id" meaning you cannot simply use `angular.element` to select an element by class or id like

```
var element = angular.element('#foo')
```

you have to use the following

```
var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#foo'))
```

You may ask, "why not use document.getElementById('#foo')?" but remember we are using jqLite so we have to use `angular.element` in order to be able to use the jqLite methods on the element.

You can use the `.triggerHandler()` instead of `.trigger()`. [jQuery triggerHandler docs](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

jqLite does not support `click()`. The workaround would be to use `.ready()`

```
element.ready(function() {
    console.log('Click');
});
```