# Equivalent of jQuery's element selector in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a jQuery implemented functionality that finds an element:

```
$('#' + id).dialog('close');
```

What's the AngularJS version of `$('#' + id)`?

Comment: I don't think the jqlit version implemented by angularjs has selector support - [angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) - so you can use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` or other methods like `document.getElementById` based on your need - or include jQuery also in your project and make full use of it

Comment: instead of $ you can use angular.element function to get the element angular.element('#'+id)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629370/jquery-trigger-equivalent-in-angularjs