# Equivalent of jQuery $ in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Novice to AngularJS. I am wondering if there is something equivalent to $ in Angular. I found that `$scope` object is an **instance** of function constructor `Scope`.I have to say that I created `$scope` without defining a controller, just by:

```
var $scope = angular.element($('#quantity')).scope();
```

where quantity is the id of an element. My question is how to access `Scope` function object. I want e.g.

```
$scope.__proto__===Scope.prototype
```

However in the right, `Scope` is unknown. **Where does it belong to? Which is its context?**

Comment: You are probably doing something you really don't need to do. Where are you using this code and what exactly are you trying to do within your app?

Comment: As I understand it, you usually don't want the equivalent of jQuery's `$` in Angular. This may be useful: [*“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: I just asked: What do I have to add in front of `Scope.prototype` in order to get true from the above comparison. Just that!

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629370/jquery-trigger-equivalent-in-angularjs

Comment: Show more code related to what you are doing or trying to do. It really looks like you are way off on a tangent here and whatever you are doing most probably has a more appropriate approach